# Complex Transformation & Joins Not Working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-database

I'm getting stumped on a complex MySQL Query.  I've tried joins, and I've tried using where X=Y clauses to merge multiple WordPress tables together.

What I am attempting to do is export WordPress users, including specific user meta data merged with activity information from another table.

If you are not familiar with WordPress's table structure, here is a summary of the relevant built in tables

**_usermeta**

| umeta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | first_name | Kevin |
| 2 | 1 | last_name | Gee |
| 3 | 1 | ID_number | 123456 |

**_users**

| ID | user_login | user_pass | ... | user_email | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kevin | ... | ... | kevin@example.com | ... |

**_posts**

| ID | ... | post_title | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | Course Name | ... |

The plug in we are using is Learn Dash, and we are trying to extract activity information from the table below

**_learndash_user_activity**

| activity_id | user_id | post_id | course_id | activity_type | activity_status | activity_started | activity_completed | activity_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | 5 | 252 | 252 | course | 1 | 1612283718 | 1614975038 | 1614975038 |
| 35 | 5 | 271 | 252 | lesson | 1 | 1612283818 | 1614976038 | 1614975034 |

To transform the meta data in to something useful, I know I can do something like this, which gets me the name, ID info and email address of the users

```
SELECT _usermeta.user_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN _usermeta.meta_key = "first_name" THEN _usermeta.meta_value END) "First Name",
MAX(CASE WHEN _usermeta.meta_key = "last_name" THEN _usermeta.meta_value END) "Last Name",
MAX(CASE WHEN _usermeta.meta_key = "ID_number" THEN _usermeta.meta_value END) "ID Number",
_users.user_email as "Email Address"
FROM _usermeta
JOIN _users on _usermeta.user_id = _users.ID
GROUP BY _usermeta.user_id
```

And, I can grab the completed course information like this

```
SELECT  
_learndash_user_activity.user_id as "User ID", 
_posts.post_title as "Course Name",
FROM_UNIXTIME(_learndash_user_activity.activity_completed) as "Completed Timestamp"      
FROM _learndash_user_activity
JOIN _posts on _learndash_user_activity.post_id = _posts.ID
WHERE 
_learndash_user_activity.activity_type = 'course' AND
_learndash_user_activity.activity_status = 1 AND
_learndash_user_activity.activity_completed IS NOT NULL
```

Which returns a table of all completed courses with the user ID's

But, when I try to merge these two queries together on another join for user_id to bring everything together, I either timeout the query as it never ends, or I get a garbage output of never ending data.

My intent is to generate a table like this

**_output**

| _usermeta.user_id | _usermeta.meta_key(first_name) | _usermeta.meta_key(last_name) | _users.user_email | _usermeta.meta_key(id_number) | _posts.post_title | _learndash_user_activity.activity_completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kevin | Gee | email_address | 123456 | Course 101 | January 31, 2021 |
| 2 | Test | User | email_address | 654321 | Course 101 | February 1, 2021 |
| 1 | Kevin | Gee | email_address | 123456 | Course 102 | February 6, 2021 |

What is the best way to merge these two queries together to return useful information similar to my table above. Is this doable with a single query?

Any advice you can provide is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to join bioth queries

```
SELECT 
    t1.user_id,
    t1.`First Name`,
    t1.`Last Name`,
    t1.`ID Number`,
    t2.`Course Name`,
    t2.`Completed Timestamp`
FROM
    (SELECT _usermeta.user_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN _usermeta.meta_key = "first_name" THEN _usermeta.meta_value END) "First Name",
    MAX(CASE WHEN _usermeta.meta_key = "last_name" THEN _usermeta.meta_value END) "Last Name",
    MAX(CASE WHEN _usermeta.meta_key = "ID_number" THEN _usermeta.meta_value END) "ID Number",
    _users.user_email as "Email Address"
    FROM _usermeta
    JOIN _users on _usermeta.user_id = _users.ID
    GROUP BY _usermeta.user_id) t1
JOIN
    (SELECT  
    _learndash_user_activity.user_id as "User ID", 
    _posts.post_title as "Course Name",
    FROM_UNIXTIME(_learndash_user_activity.activity_completed) as "Completed Timestamp"      
    FROM _learndash_user_activity
    JOIN _posts on _learndash_user_activity.post_id = _posts.ID
    WHERE 
    _learndash_user_activity.activity_type = 'course' AND
    _learndash_user_activity.activity_status = 1 AND
    _learndash_user_activity.activity_completed IS NOT NULL) te ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! I was wondering if nested Selects like that was possible! And it is :-D  This is nice and elegant! I appreciate your help